# cakephpのヘルパーについて

Tags: php, cakephp

以下のURLのcakephpのチュートリアルを進めていて、疑問に思ったのですが、
例えば、foreachで出力した＄dataを使ってfindのヘルパーでデータベースから検索といったプログラムを作る場合、どうすればいいのでしょうか？
index.ctpのファイル上でfindヘルパーは使えないと思うのですが。。

詳しい方、ご教示ください。
http://libro.tuyano.com/index3?id=755001&page=3

Answer (score 1):

[アソシエーション](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)を設定しているのでもなければ、コントローラ側でそれぞれ find しておくことになるかと思います。動作確認はしてないですが、こんな感じで。

```
function index() {
    ...

    $datas = $this->MyModel->find('list');
    $submodels = array();
    foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
        $submodels[$key] = $this->SubModel->find('list', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'SubModel.mainkey' => $key
            )
        ));
    }
    $this->set('datas',$datas);
    $this->set('submodels',$submodels);
}

<?php foreach ($datas as $key => $data): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $data; ?></h2>
    <?php foreach ($submodels[$key] as $submodel): ?>
        <?php echo $submodel; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

ここでは MyModel のプライマリキーをキーとした配列に SubModel の find 結果を入れていますが、どういうデータを取得するか、ビュー側に渡すかによって、ここの取得方法や構造は変わってきます。

Answer (score 1):

Ajaxを使えば、CakePHPのMVCを壊さずに、ControllerでViewを意識しすぎることもなく実装できます。

Controllerのほう

```
<?php
// ※こっちだけ追記
function ajax($data_id){
    $record = $this->MySampleData->findById($data_id);
    $this->set('record', $record['MySampleData']);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['record']);
}
// ※何も手を付けていません
function index(){
    $this->layout = "Sample";
    $this->set("header_for_layout","Sample Application");
    $this->set("footer_for_layout","copyright by SYODA-Tuyano. 2011.");

    $datas = $this->MySampleData->find('list');
    $this->set('datas',$datas);
}
?>
```

index.ctp

```
<h1>Index Page</h1>
<p>MySampleData Index View.</p>
<table>
<?php foreach ($datas as $id=>$data): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="data" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $data; ?></div>
            <div class="data-extra"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<script>
// クリックすると更に検索
$('.data').click(function(){
    var elem = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.json?id='+$(elem).attr('data-id'), // ここは書き換えてください
        type: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            $('.data-extra', elem).html(json.record.extra); // 大雑把だけれど
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('通信エラー');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

一気に検索するならアソシエーションを使うべきですが、個々に検索でいいのなら、私はこのほうがベターだと思います。ControllerがViewのために使われないかもしれないデータまで毎回ロードするというのは非常に無駄です。

HelperでControllerを呼び出すことは可能ですが、すべきではないです。
同様に、$this->set('Controller', $this)などで渡すのもしないほうがいいです。
MVCの意味がなくなってしまいますからね。